# Create a New line in a Word Link without double "" around result

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-word

Thanks in advance

How to get this Result

```
 RandomText1
 RandomText2
```

to appear in a word link to excel

In Excel I'm using a Formula

```
=SUBSTITUTE("RandomText1SomeRandomText2","RandomText2",CHAR(10) & "RandomText2",1)
```

to force a new line in a link result in word

I have a link in a word docx

```
LINK Excel.SheetMacroEnabled.12 "C:\\MyFile.xlsm" MySheet!MyRange \t \* CHARFORMAT
```

and I'd like to have the line break appear in the result.

My field works **only the result is always surrounded by double quotes**

eg

```
"RandomText1 
 RandomText2"
```

not

```
 RandomText1
 RandomText2
```

How can I change the excel formula or the field to get rid of the double quotes around the result in the word link result?

nB The text is variable and can be anything (changes each time).

Comment: I have a macro based solution.
I create the word doc and update all the word docs with a macro so the following solution is invoked at that time only is not acceptable for the reasons below.  
  
'Convert the formula in the cell to text
Generate the Word Doc then Update the field with Field Update set to Manual
Convert the cell back to a formula'  
  
This is not satisfactory as subsequent edits and updates are surrounded by the quotes.  
I need this to work "natively"..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use
    LINK Excel.SheetMacroEnabled.12 "C:\MyFile.xlsm" MySheet!MyRange \r * CHARFORMAT